# Get error when I install .net core on Mac OS and Ubuntu

Tags: .net-core

I follow the steps here: http://dotnet.github.io/getting-started/

But always get error like below:

**On MAC OS**

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Console, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at System.Console.WriteLine(String value)
>
> at HelloWorldSample.Program.Main()

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Comment: I use default project.json created by "dotnet init"

Comment: I ran into this error today as well and haven't found a solution.

Comment: @BlakeBeaupain or @Hunter - did you do `dotnet restore` first, before running your application? Did the restore process succeed?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you missed the `dotnet restore` step. If not, check for errors that occurred during that step. It is what pulls in the extra packages via NuGet.

Unlike previous versions of .NET Framework, in which all of the assemblies were typically shipped together, .NET Core is very modular and your project will only pull in the ones it needs.